# React Router Server Render Client-Sessions info

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using mozilla client-sessions with express/node and am trying to within my standard * request figure out how I can pass my session.user to the react-router.  I know it is probably something easy that I'm missing and maybe I'll get it myself but I have tried  and  but I am losing it to undefined somewhere in the mix.  Any thoughts? If I can do this it will lift any and all limitations on my server render/universal

```
app.get("*", (req: any, res) => {
    var props = {
        user: res.locals.user
    };
    var html = renderToString(<SiteRouter history={createMemoryHistory(req.url)} {...props} />);
    res.render("layout", { ReactMarkup: html, meta: getMeta(req.url) });
    res.end();
});

export class SiteRouter extends React.Component<{ history?: any, routes?: any, children?: any, user?: any }, {}> {
    render() {
        var props = {
            user: this.props.user
        }; // user is alive here but I seem to be losing it going into the router and then its (router's) child routes.
        return <Router history={this.props.history} routes={routes} {...props} />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can't attach props to the actual react-router. I had to pass them down from express through a callback on my routes modules to pass data to the top level component and render it synchronously. Probably not best practice but this whole server-rendering concept seems to be all over the map everywhere.  Thanks anyways.